# LINQ query fails when I run it from an Azure Function, but not from a console app

Tags: linq, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm moving some code from a traditional worker role to an Azure Function. I've found a line of code that returns a result when I call it from a console app, but null when I call it from a function.

Now, for some example code. I wrote a _resultProvider class that basically queries an underlying CosmosDB database -- at the base class, it creates an IOrderedQueryable query and filters it based on the predicate that you pass in as a parameter. The first line of code returns a result only when I call it from a console app, and null if I call it from an Azure Function. The second line returns a result from either platform.

Gets result when called from the worker role, but null when called from the function:

```
var res1 = _resultProvider.GetSpecialAsync(o => id == o.Id).Result.FirstOrDefault();
```

Gets result from either the worker role or the function:

```
var res2 = _resultProvider.GetSpecialAsync(o => 1 == 1).Result.Where(o=>id==o.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

I'm guessing this is some kind of LINQ issue, because passing the predicate along doesn't seem to work from the function, but it works if I just get all the results and query that result set.

Here's the GetSpecialAsync code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsSpecialAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    IDocumentQuery<T> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId),
            new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true})
        .Where(predicate)
        .AsDocumentQuery();

    List<T> results = new List<T>();
    while (query.HasMoreResults)
    {
        results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
    }

    return results;
}
```

Here's the type I'm attempting to return, ResultDocVm:

```
public class ResultDocVm : DocViewModelBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long AccountId { get; set; }
    // ... insert more junk here with getters and setters
}
```

Here's DocViewModelBase:

```
public abstract class DocViewModelBase
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    //... even more junk here
}
```

Comment: It would really help to know what's in GetSpecialAsync

Comment: @NickChapsas I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Ok lets take it step by step. Just to make sure it's not some sort of indexing issue, can you set the `EnableScanInQuery` in FeedOptions to true and see what happens?

Comment: I know it sounds weird but I had inconsistency in results from FirstOrDefault as well with equality operators in LINQ. Also try using .Equals for the id instead of ==

Comment: Also i don't quite know about the synchronization context of azure functions but you should always use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `.Wait()` and `.Result`

Comment: @NickChapsas I tried using .Equals, setting EnableScanInQuery to true, and removed the FirstOrDefault() from the expression. Still no luck -- GetItemsSpecialAsync still returns 0 results.

Comment: Can i see the object you are using as T? I am particularly interested in the Id property

Comment: @NickChapsas Sure -- see my updated question.

Comment: Can you print `query` once composed to see what it generates?

Comment: @NickChapsas Sure, it's: {{"query":"SELECT * FROM root WHERE (\"d015ba7e-47a7-45b3-9ff6-26009c4f3801\" = root[\"Id\"]) "}}

Comment: Is that also what the Console app generates as well or is the `Id` lowercase in the console app?

Comment: It looks like the fact that the function doesn't make the `Id`  lowercase is the problem. You can actually try it yourself by running the following queries in the data explorer. This will work `SELECT * FROM root WHERE ("d015ba7e-47a7-45b3-9ff6-26009c4f3801" = root["id"])` and this will fail `SELECT * FROM root WHERE ("d015ba7e-47a7-45b3-9ff6-26009c4f3801" = root["Id"])`

Comment: @NickChapsas Just a sec -- I'm still trying to make a good prototype to test through the console (my previous method was kind of a Rube Golberg machine). Will post the results after I get that running.

Comment: @NickChapsas Arg, I think you were right! Here's the console version of the query: {{"query":"SELECT * FROM root WHERE (\"d015ba7e-47a7-45b3-9ff6-26009c4f3801\" = root[\"id\"]) "}}

Comment: @NickChapsas Is there anything I can do about that? Is it just a weird LINQ bug?

Comment: The test is simple. Make your property `id` lowercase and test again.

Comment: If Azure Functions ignore attributes then there is not much you can do other than making the id lowercase OR writing a method to manually replace the expression body part of the `Id` parameter with the equal part of the `id` parameter

Comment: @NickChapsas Okay, thanks for all your hard work in helping me pin down this issue. Since my lead dev doesn't want me refactoring everything, I can't use lowercase id. But one thing I CAN do is use .StartsWith which seems to circumvent this issue.

Comment: Sounds good enough to me. I will write up the answer. Approve it when you find a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after all the back and forth it looks like the Console App is taking the `JsonProperty` attribute into account while the Azure Function doesn't.

This generates a query which will return no results because the `Id` property will be uppercased and not lowercased ie `id`.

It sounds like a bug with the Azure Function at the Azure level and not with your code per se.

Comment: Thanks. And for everyone else reading this who hasn't gone through the comments on the original question, you can circumvent this by using StartsWith instead of testing for equality.

Comment: Nick -- it looks like the temporary workaround is no longer working. I've been trying to see if I can manually replace the expression body like you mentioned in a previous comment, but I'm stumped. Can you point me in the right direction? How does one replace expression bodies?